# Presence of a strip on another NLA track prevents execution of original track

Tags: nla-editor, actions

Using the default cube, create a keyframe at frame 1 where y=-4 and a keyframe at frame 40 where y=4.

[image]

Change the action just created to an NLA strip on a new NLA track.

[image]

With the current frame=20, Use the NLA editor to split the NLA strip in half via Edit>Split Strips. Drag the 2nd half to frames 40-60.

[image]

At this point, playing the animation will result in the cube moving from y=-4 to y=0, remaining stationary between frames 20 & 40 and then from frame 40 onward continuing from y=0 to y=4.

I now add a new action between frames 20 & 40 that rotates by 90 degrees and add it as an NLA strip.

If all 3 NLA strips reside on the same NLA track, the animation now plays as expected. Translation, rotation, translation.

[image]

However, if the rotation strip is moved to it's own NLA track, this changes.

[image]

In this situation, there is
translation from frames 0-20,
rotation from frames 20-40 but
nothing from frames 40-60

The presence of the rotation strip between 20-40 prevents the 2nd part of the translation from occuring.

In the NLA right panel, I've tried all the various Extrapolation combinations for all 3 NLA strips.

What am I doing wrong here here?

Blender v2.83.3 on Linux

[image]

Comment: I haven't read everything but have you tried to select your top strip and in the NLA right panel (press N to display) > Active Strip > Extrapolation > Choose Nothing instead of Hold

Comment: Thanks moonboots. Was unaware of those options, but have now tried them all & amended the question.